# Angular filtering doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my template I have this code:

```
 <li class="row timeline-item" data-ng-repeat="item in data | filter:workoutFilter" data-ng-include="getTemplateUrl(item)"></li>
```

And in my controller I have:

```
   $scope.workoutFilter = null;
  $rootScope.$on('workout', function(e, data) {
        $scope.workoutFilter = "{Type: 'workout'}";
    });
```

When I click button workouts, everything just disappears as if there are no items that match this filter, but that isn't the case (and I know this for a fact because getTemplateUrl detects type workout and returns right template)

Why is this happening ? Is there any other way I can filter items which have property Type "workout" ?

**EDIT**

Here is what happens when I click button:

In my other controller :

```
$scope.onWorkoutsClick = function () {
    feedService.setWorkoutFilter();
};
```

In service:

```
setWorkoutFilter : function() {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('workout');
    }
```

And in my main controller:

```
$rootScope.$on('workout', function(e, data) {
        $scope.workoutFilter = "{Type: 'workout'}";
    });
```

Comment: what function are you performing when you click the button workouts? can you provide that code?

Comment: @DavidMichaelHarrison sure, I've edited my post and included code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're trying to filter based on `item.Type == 'workout'`?

You need to set your filter to an object rather than a string:

```
$scope.workoutFilter = {Type: 'workout'};
```